# Flutter: where can we use linear gradient instead of container

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients

I want to put a LinearGradient instead of using Container's BoxDecorations,

For example:

```
return CustomSlidingSegmentedControl<int>(
  children: myTabs,
  innerPadding: 2,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  thumbColor: [HERE I WANT TO USE LINEAR-GRADIENT],
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3F3F3),
  radius: 30.0,
  onValueChanged: (i) {
    this.index = i;
    widget.onChanged(i);
  },
);
```

If you know a solution, your share would be helpful!

Also if my instruction is insufficient, please let me know where I should add it.

Thank you in advance:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the CustomSlidingSegmentedControl widget in a container with Linear Gradient.

```
return Container(
  decoration:
  BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient()),
  child: CustomSlidingSegmentedControl<int>(
  children: myTabs),
  innerPadding: 2,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3F3F3),
  radius: 30.0,
  onValueChanged: (i) {
    this.index = i;
    widget.onChanged(i);
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I'm sorry that I had a problem with your idea: The argument type 'Container' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<int, Widget>'. Would please you suggest solving this phenomenon? Thank you again:)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the widget in Container as mentioned now?

Comment: I had tried and the error was gone. But unfortunately, the output wasn't what I wanted. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NjObSvL3vViyenteeZ6oLrN2cCIXQSQx/view?usp=sharing) is the result.